# How to set space between statusBar and navigationBar?

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uistatusbar

Is it possible at all? I simply add left and right bar button items. Is there a way to put some offset there?

Comment: Need to add custom navigation bar or use large title with navigation bar

Answer (score 0):

Add a `UIView` from storyboard and make its height 44 and tops constraint as required space you want.
Add those above mentioned elements you want.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve the same is to use a custom View Controller and add navigation controller as a child on it with top constraint of some pixels or change its y origin.